# I don't understand な in this sentence

Tags: grammar, usage, nuances

まだ何度でも食べたいと 欲張ってしまうな

So I know an imperative negative like 飲むな means don't drink, but in this case the speaker is talking about himself and his inability to not stop his own desire. why is this not 欲張ってしまわない instead of 欲張ってしまうな.

Thank You!

Comment: Duplicate/related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/48917/what-does-this-%e3%81%aa-at-the-end-of-the-sentence-mean , https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33969/when-is-na-used-at-the-end-of-a-sentence/33973#33973

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is "na" used at the end of a sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33969/when-is-na-used-at-the-end-of-a-sentence)

Answer (score 1):

な can also be a sentence-ending particle, having relatively the same meaning as ね sentence-ending particle except having a bit tougher or manlier nuance as books usually like to call it.